# Am I able to change the name of /wp-admin/options-general.php?

Tags: wp-admin, backbone

I'm asking this question because I am coding a Wordpress plugin, and I want to be able to detect when WP-Admin is using options-general.php. Currently, I'm just checking the URL directly to see if it ends with options-general.php, but if Wordpress allows installations to change the filenames of this file, then my plugin may not work on certain installations.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you need to do this? What problem does it solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, though I would rely on the Screen object, not the URL

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen

Comment: The function doesn't exist in options-general.php though. Do I have to call it through the 'current_screen' hook?

Comment: It does, but it's possible to run your code before those files are loaded if you use the wrong hooks, see the usage restrictions in the docs

Comment: I looked into it and realised that I need to put my hook after admin_init, which is pretty low on the action hierarchy. Since I'm making a URL to receive AJAX requests on WP-Admin, I figure I'd just check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] directly.